# refresh div after sending data to db

Tags: php, html, ajax, refresh

i have a div that shows the total sum of some products:

```
<div class="total-price"><?php echo (!empty($cart)) ? $cart['total'] : '0'; ?> $</div>
```

with ajax, i'm adding products to cart ... se the page is not reloading.
How to refresh the div after I add the product to cart?

The ajax that i'm using:

```
<script>
$('#order-to-cart').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/tdt/order',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $(".success-message").slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp();
            $(".total-price").something...;
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You aren't calling anything that would reload the page on `success`.

Comment: Wait what do you mean by "refresh"? You can't "refresh" a div you'd have to refresh the page OR just add something to the div.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
<script>
$('#order-to-cart').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/tdt/order',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function () {
            $(".success-message").slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp();
            var oldPrice = $('.total-price').text() * 1;
            var itemPrice = "15"; //the price that should be added
            $('.total-price').text(oldPrice + itemPrice);
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be returning a total basket value from your /tdt/order path.

In the PHP script you should echo some JSON data with all the required information, for example

```
echo json_encode(array("totalPrice" => "£10.01"));
```

Then you need to parse this information into your Javascript and update the pages elements;

```
<script>
$('#order-to-cart').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/tdt/order',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $(".success-message").slideDown().delay(5000).slideUp();
            $('.total-price').val(data.totalPrice);
        }
    });
})
</script>
```

The above ajax request will expect the data returned to be JSON, you will then use this to update the total-price element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like angularjs or knockoutjs - for angular you would update your model - for knockout you would use the self.object.push(value) i.e.,

```
    
      function OrderViewModel() {
```

`var self = this;            
        self.myOrder = ko.observableArray([]);

        self.addOrderItem = function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                url: "yourURL",
                data: $("#YOURFORMFIELDID").serialize(),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (value) {
                    self.myOrder.push(value);
                },
                headers: {
                    'RequestVerificationToken': '@TokenHeaderValue()'
                }
            });

        }
   }
 ko.applyBindings(new orderViewModel());
</script>
</pre>`

Comment: if you're not using the verification tokens to prevent csfr then just remove the "headers" portion